# telebot крашит, при попытке выполнить команду

Tags: python, telebot, ос

Решил написать бота которому ты отправляешь команду а он её исполняет у себя, и результат отправляет
Всё работало но решил я ввести c:/ и тут это чудо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

незнаю что с этим делать вот код:

```
import os
import telebot;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен');


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def startCmd(message):
    mess = message.text
    print(mess)
    date = str(os.popen(mess).read())
    date = str(date.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866'))
    print(date)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, date)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Файл, который пытается открыть `popen`, точно существует?

Comment: а если не существует, то допустим она об этом и говорит. Но бот крашится на попытке отправки ответа

Comment: Дополнительно обрабатывайте `date`, чтобы значение не могло быть пустым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда `cd c:/` успешно исполняется, но она возвращает пустую строку.

А метод [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) требует строку, содержащую как минимум 1 символ:

> Text of the message to be sent, 1-4096 characters after entities
> parsing